# How to pass await and async functions to WebdriverIO execute function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, webdriver, webdriver-io

I have the problem.

I want to execute a script on the browser side using latest features like await, async....

Here is what I tried to do

```
 client.addCommand('getBinaryImage', function () {
            var self = this;
            return self.execute(
                function downloadImageBinary(url) {

                    const imageResponse = await httpGetPromise(url, 'blob');
                    alert(imageResponse);

                }
            );
        });
```

I cannot compile this code, cause it outputs the following error

```
    const imageResponse = await httpGetPromise(url, 'blob');
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

If I try to set function to async like that

```
                async function downloadImageBinary(url) {
                ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

How can I pass such code to the browser to be executed ?

Comment: what version of nodejs? async/await is relatively new

Comment: My current version is v7.3.0

Comment: best bet is to upgrade to 8.4.0 - 7.x isn't being developed anymore

Comment: @bxfvgekd did you try to use `browser.executeAsync(script,arguments);` ?